# Don't have the required permissions (Microsoft.Sql/register/action)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

A user belongs to the Owner Role for the Resource Group.  When he goes to create a SQL Database, he receives the error that "You don't have the required permissions (Microsoft.SQL/register/action)".  Strangely he receives the error in the Subscription box, and not in the Resource Group box (see screenshot).  Do I need to grant him additional privileges at the Subscription level to get this to work?

[image]

Comment: Do you read this article - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-configure/ ? maybe it will help you

Comment: Does this user have permissions at the subscription level?

Comment: They didn't.  I opened a ticket with Microsoft and they suggested giving the user Contributor permissions at the subscription level as a troubleshooting step.  That did allow them to create a SQL DB, but it isn't a permanent solution because that gives them access to do things across the entire subscription that they shouldn't have.

Comment: See edited answer below, since I can't add a picture here (that I know of.)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you got a temporary workaround in place: Try granting [SQL DB Contributor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/#sql-db-contributor), which should be able to create/manage SQL Databases; If that has too many permissions, you can [create a custom role in Azure RBAC](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-control-custom-roles/).

I can't include pictures in comments, apparently; can you enumerate the permissions that user has so I can attempt to reproduce correctly? In my attempts, the a user given `SQL DB Contributor` on the resource group was sufficient to create a database.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I tried that first and this is the response that I got from Microsoft Support that fixed the issue.

Azure SQL DB Contributor role does not grant access to create databases. This is simply how it is configured from our end, however you can give the user permissions on the master database level:

To create an additional account that can create databases you must create a user in master, and add the user to the special dbmanager database role. The user can be a contained database user, or a user based on a SQL Server login in the virtual master database.

Comment: I should have seen that coming; I was too quick to comment. I assume the permissions error you saw would also be thrown by [SQL Server Contributor](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/role-based-access-built-in-roles/#sql-server-contributor). I was aware of the TSQL/SQLRBAC based solution, but figured you wanted to rely on Azure RBAC.

Comment: Same issue for me as OP.. I was added as a SQL DB COntributor but still receive this error while trying to create any sql databases in Azure